# Google Script: Application skips valid urls

Tags: google-apps-script

My code is below

So my problem is it works fine but it should skip a url like:
http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1 because it doesnt exist.

But a url like this exists http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=2

If I test my app without the loop it will give this error but still add it to db. Heres the error:

```
Request failed for http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=undefined returned
```

Error ^ so I am assuming it skips it cuz of it but i don't want it to skip that error just the ones that don't exist. Please help.

```
var address = 'ip';
var user = 'user';
var userPwd = 'pw';
var db = 'db';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

function getJSON(id) {

  var url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=" + id;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get api endpoint
  var json = response.getContentText(); // get the response content as text
  var data = JSON.parse(json)

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO items '
      + '(name, description, itemid, img) values (?, ?, ?, ?)');
  stmt.setString(1,data.item.name);
  stmt.setString(2, data.item.description);
  stmt.setString(3,data.item.id);
  stmt.setString(4, data.item.icon);
  stmt.execute();
}

for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
  try{
    Utilities.sleep(6000);
    getJSON(i);
  } catch(e) {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the muteHttpExceptions parameter with the fetch() method to know where exactly the problem is.

Change:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get api endpoint
```

To:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}); 
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

Check the logs for any errors.

Comment: Still does the same thing skips a ton of valid urls.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further checking, you may want to get the response code of the url then add the script for saving to DB.

```
function myFunction() {
// Construct `fetch` params object
var params = {
'muteHttpExceptions' : true
};
// The code below logs the HTTP status code from the response received
// when fetching the Google home page.
// It should be 200 if the request succeeded.
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1", params);
Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
}
```

For more information check the tutorials and forums regarding validation of URL using Google Apps Script:

- [Debugging external host communication with UrlFetchApp](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/debugging-external-host-communication-with-urlfetchapp/)
- [Check if URL exists](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/mz_bJ5x_zOA)

From the debugging external host:

```
// Construct `fetch` params object
var params = {
'muteHttpExceptions' : true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)

// Check return code embedded in response.
var rc = response.getResponseCode();
var responseText = response.getContentText();
if (rc !== 200) {
// Log HTTP Error
Logger.log("Response (%s) %s",
rc,
responseText );
// Could throw an exception yourself, if appropriate
}
else {
// Successful POST, handle response normally
Logger.log( responseText );
}
```

You can try if it will return 200 then insert to DB if not, ignore the URL.

Hope this helps!